# MySQL check before soft delete

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, soft-delete

I'm using MySQL. I have a record on `A` table with a soft delete column: `active` with a value of `0`.

This row is linked to 11 tables. All have the same  `active` column.

I need to be sure that the record on `A` is deleted **only if** all the references across the 11 tables have `active = 0` also.

I know I can write a view with these queries to get if I can "deleted" or not. But this is one example and IMO not very practical solution. Cascade update won't work either because I **can't** delete the parent row if any of the child is still active.

Thanks!

Comment: You say: I need to be sure that the record on `A` is deleted **only if** all the references across the 11 tables have `active = 0` also. By deleted, do you mean hard delete or soft delete (set active = 0)

Comment: This can get messy, perhaps consider a fk to restrict deletes, which means you'd always need to delete the children before the parent.

Comment: @SteveMandl Yes. Say you have a Student. You can't delete (Active = 0) if he/she still is on a course (active = 1 on Students_Courses table). I need to keep both records for history logs.

Comment: @Augwa Thanks, but that check will be ok if no relations exists but it won't check if I'm **allowed** to safe delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you create the active_view as you said you could. Just add the active flags of all the related tables into the foreign_active column, and you should be good to go.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_update_student
 BEFORE UPDATE ON student  FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
      IF NEW.active = 0 AND (SELECT foreign_active FROM active_view
           WHERE id = NEW.id) > 0
      THEN
           SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot delete student when active roles exist.';
      END IF;
 END;
```

Comment: Ok, so If I've 11 tables I should check all of them, let's say, by hand? Is there a generic -and faster- way?

Comment: In the database, there is probably not a more elegant way. If mysql supported sub-queries in check constraints, you could add check constraints for each related table. I don't think this is any better though. You could enforce this in your application, then there may be something clever you could do using subscribe/notify or object inheritance.

Comment: mmm I have the feeling that doing this is wrong but all the searches I did end in something like this. I think the sooner I start writing the better. Thanks!